# How to fire an event on Vue switch change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a Vue component that has a vue-switch element. When the component is loaded, the switch has to be set to ON or OFF depending on the data. This is currently happening within the 'mounted()' method. Then, when the switch is toggled, it needs to make an API call that will tell the database the new state. This is currently happening in the 'watch' method.

The problem is that because I am 'watching' the switch, the API call runs when the data gets set on mount. So if it's set to ON and you navigate to the component, the mounted() method sets the switch to ON but it ALSO calls the toggle API method which turns it off. Therefore the view says it's on but the data says it's off.

I have tried to change the API event so that it happens on a click method, but this doesn't work as it doesn't recognize a click and the function never runs.

How do I make it so that the API call is only made when the switch is clicked?

HTML

```
<switcher size="lg" color="green" open-name="ON" close-name="OFF" v-model="toggle"></switcher>
```

VUE

```
data: function() {
    return {
        toggle: false,
        noAvailalableMonitoring: false
    }
},
computed: {
    report() { return this.$store.getters.currentReport },
    isBeingMonitored() { return this.$store.getters.isBeingMonitored },
    availableMonitoring() { return this.$store.getters.checkAvailableMonitoring }
},
mounted() {
    this.toggle = this.isBeingMonitored;
},
watch: {
    toggle: function() {
      if(this.availableMonitoring) {
          let dto = {
            reportToken: this.report.reportToken,
            version: this.report.version
          }
          this.$store.dispatch('TOGGLE_MONITORING', dto).then(response => {
          }, error => {
          console.log("Failed.")
      }) 
    } else {
        this.toggle = false;
        this.noAvailalableMonitoring = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "I have tried to change the API event so that it happens on a click method, but this doesn't work" Where is your attempt at this? Click should work fine.

Comment: I took it out because it didn't work but I changed the toggle watch to a method and added @click="toggleMonitoring()" to the switch element but the method never ran when it was clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using a 2-way computed property for your model (Vue 2).
Attempted to update code here, but obvs not tested without your Vuex setup.
For reference, please see [Two-Way Computed Property](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/forms.html)

```
data: function(){
  return {
    noAvailableMonitoring: false
  }
},
computed: {
  report() { return this.$store.getters.currentReport },
  isBeingMonitored() { return this.$store.getters.isBeingMonitored },
  availableMonitoring() { return this.$store.getters.checkAvailableMonitoring },
  toggle: {
    get() {
      return this.$store.getters.getToggle;
    },
    set() {
      if(this.availableMonitoring) {
        let dto = {
          reportToken: this.report.reportToken,
          version: this.report.version
        }
        this.$store.dispatch('TOGGLE_MONITORING', dto).then(response => {
        }, error => {
          console.log("Failed.")
        });
      } else {
        this.$store.commit('setToggle', false);
        this.noAvailableMonitoring = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having a `watch`, create a new computed named `clickToggle`. Its `get` function returns `toggle`, its `set` function does what you're doing in your `watch` (as well as, ultimately, setting `toggle`). Your `mounted` can adjust `toggle` with impunity. Only changes to `clickToggle` will do the other stuff.